# UIView move in circle path (Not animation)

Tags: ios

I have UIView and I must to move it in circle path.

[image]

Comment: OK, now that you have told us what you want to do, please update your question to ask an actual question. What have you tried so far? What exactly do you need help with? Remember, you need to ask a specific programming question.

Comment: ... the question seemed ok to me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. Add the UIImageView to a subclass of UIView, which has a property for the image so you can move it in code. Implement touchesBegan:... touchesMoved:... and touchesEnded:... to move the image to the appropriate point on the circle. There's some simple math there:

EDIT: added some comments, and fixed the quadrant bug.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    CGPoint viewCenter = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    CGPoint imageOrigin = self.imageOnCircle.frame.origin;
    CGSize imageSize = self.imageOnCircle.frame.size;
    CGPoint imageCenter = CGPointMake(imageOrigin.x + imageSize.width/2,
                                      imageOrigin.y + imageSize.height/2);

    CGFloat xDist = imageCenter.x - viewCenter.x;
    CGFloat yDist = imageCenter.y - viewCenter.y;
    CGFloat radius = sqrt(xDist*xDist + yDist*yDist);

    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGFloat touchXDist = touchPoint.x - viewCenter.x;
    CGFloat touchYDist = touchPoint.y - viewCenter.y;

    // angles in the view coordinates are measured from the positive x axis
    //  positive value means clockwise rotation
    //  -π/2 is vertically upward (towards the status bar)
    //  π/2 is vertically downward (towards the home button)

    CGFloat newAngle = atanf(touchYDist / touchXDist);
    // arctan takes a value between -π/2 and π/2

    CGFloat newXDist = radius * cosf(newAngle);
    // cos has a value between -1 and 1
    // since the angle is between -π/2 and π/2, newXDist will always be positive.
    if (touchXDist < 0)
        newXDist *= -1;

    CGFloat newYDist = radius * sinf(newAngle);
    // sin has a value between -1 and 1
    // since the angle is between -π/2 and π/2, newYDist can attain all its values.
    // however, the sign will be flipped when x is negative.
    if (touchXDist < 0)
        newYDist *= -1;

    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(viewCenter.x + newXDist,
                                    viewCenter.y + newYDist);
    CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(newCenter.x - self.imageOnCircle.frame.size.width/2,
                                    newCenter.y - self.imageOnCircle.frame.size.height/2);
    self.imageOnCircle.frame = CGRectMake(newOrigin.x,
                                          newOrigin.y,
                                          self.imageOnCircle.frame.size.width,
                                          self.imageOnCircle.frame.size.height);
}
```

Also, you might want to add a max / min angle, to limit the movement to one side or the other...

Comment: thank. my problem that I bad understand how to calculate new position with cos, sin...

Comment: Ah. Check out the [wikipedia page for trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent). Also, to fix the quadrant bug, just set the sign of `newXDist` to be the same as the sign for `touchXDist`.

Comment: It works better now, and is more readable.

Comment: Glad to help! Also, check out this, much clearer than wikipedia, [math link](http://mathmistakes.info/facts/TrigFacts/learn/uc/sign.html).